# How do I get the source of a ContextMenu-originated event in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview, contextmenu

I have a TreeView with a ContextMenu with Click events. When the click event in the context menu fires, I get the MenuItem as the source of the event, obviously. How can I get which node in the TreeView was the one who triggered the ContextMenu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you store the TreeView node (e.g. the source of the pop-up event, maybe the selected node - depends on your interface to some degree) in a private class-level variable in the ContextMenu's "pop-up" event, then refer to that variable in the menu's click event.

Comment: That's a good idea. Do you know if the popup event is ContextMenuOpening? Because neither ContextMenuOpening nor ContextMenuClosing are firing when I open the menu.

Comment: Should be the Opened event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.opened.aspx

Comment: Ok, I'm using telerik's treeview and it doesn't have an Opened event, but I managed to do it with the MouseRightButtonUp event. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, I was trying to use the Opened event in the TreeView rather than the ContextMenu. I'll use it in the ContextMenu now.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you are using `RoutedUICommands` you can use the `OriginalSource` property on `ExecuteRoutedEventArgs` and `CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs` to find the `FrameworkElement` where `Command` started its bubble.

The `OriginalSource` however maybe the inner TextBlock, or other element in the node's DataTemplate, so you will need to use the VisualTreeHelper to find the parent you want. I have implemented a wrapper around this functionality that is similar to: 
http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent/

This approach is good if you want to separate/centralise your command logic in a large application.

Comment: I've had very good luck using the DataContext property on the OriginalSource when going all-the-way with data binding.  OriginalSource should always be a FrameworkElement.

Comment: My problem is solved for now but your solution seems pretty good. I'll check it out in the next few days. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

//there has got to be a better way than this...
TreeViewItem tvi = (((sender as MenuItem).Parent as ContextMenu).Parent as Popup).PlacementTarget as TreeViewItem;

This works, but why SHOULDN'T I do it this way?